# I know its returning the value in the tuple from the first index of the contour but how contour[:, :, 0].argmin() is working?

Tags: python, numpy

```
cnts= cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
print(extLeft)
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
print(extRight)
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
print(extTop)
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
print(extBot)
```

I could't get how its returning the maximum end points at each direction?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you not understand what argmin and argmax do?

Comment: actually i'm unable to understand the way it is giving me extreme values at each direction

Answer (score 0):

- `[:, :, 0]` - first column/row in last dimension
- `x.argmin()` returns index of a minimum value of `x` - note that this is `int`, not `tuple`, thus `c[c[:,:,0].argmin()]` is 2D
- `x[0]` - reduces 2D array to 1D

I suggest checking how this works with some simple array like `np.arange(1000).reshape(...)` instead of something complicated. Then it's easier to understand what happens in different stages.

Comment: thanks a lot.. can you provide me some best resources to learn more in clear way